# How to prevent or avoid running update delete statements without where clauses in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to prevent or avoid running  update delete statements without where clauses in oracle? Pls help with this

Comment: Question is unclear.  Please explain further, possibly with examples.

Comment: You can write `WHERE 1 = 1` or `WHERE EMP_ID = EMP_ID` or `WHERE SYSDATE IS NOT NULL` - all three where conditions will delete the entire table. What is your intention?

Comment: When i run the update statement without where clause t the statement do not run its throws some error its r useful to reduce the manual error

Comment: For example run the below statement it wil don’t run its throw some error—— update T1 set col1=0;  it don’t run raise error pls add the where clause

Comment: What error do you get? How are you running these statements? On the face of it the UPDATE you posted should run. So you need to post enough detail that we can explain whatever is going on.

Comment: I think he wants to prevent someone to run a full-open DML statement.

Comment: What i am expect here, update statement don’t run without where clause. If i run the following wry it needs to throw error— update t1 set col1=0; i don’t want to the qry will not excute its needs to throw error

Comment: Yes old programmer u catch it

Comment: Other than putting all DML in a stored proc, and validating the statements, I do now know of a solution.  Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the wrong thing to do.  It would be better to have some combination of:

(A) revoking access from people who cannot be trusted
(B) giving access through a PL/SQL layer that will limit users to pre-defined operations
(C) sizing your database with enough UNDO to flashback if there is some kind of catastrophic mistake.

However, you can *sort of* do what you want using fine-grained auditing.  Basically, make an audit handler that errors out if the current SQL has no filters.  It would be easily fooled though.

Here is an example:

```
-- Create a table we want to protect
drop table matt1;
create table matt1 ( a number );
-- Put some data into it
insert into matt1 
select level from dual connect by rownum <= 100;

commit;

-- Create an audit handler that will protect our table from wide-open updates
-- or deletes    
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE matt_table_protector_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE table_protector ( schema_name VARCHAR2, table_Name VARCHAR2, policy_name VARCHAR2 );
END matt_table_protector_pkg;
/    

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY matt_table_protector_pkg AS

  PROCEDURE table_protector ( schema_name VARCHAR2, table_Name VARCHAR2, policy_name VARCHAR2 ) IS
    l_filter_count NUMBER;
  BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ' || SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL');

     select count(*)
     into l_filter_count
     from table(dbms_xplan.display(format=>'PREDICATE'))
     where plan_table_output like '% - filter(%'
     and plan_table_output not like '%SYS_AUDIT(%';

     IF l_filter_count = 0 THEN
       raise_application_error(-20001, 'Unrestricted DML is not allowed on this table.');
     END IF;
  END;

END matt_table_protector_pkg;
/
```

Next, we Create a fine-grained audit policy to make sure our package is called whenever there is an update or delete on our table.

```
--EXEC DBMS_FGA.drop_policy (object_schema => user, object_name => 'MATT1', policy_name => 'PROTECT_MATT1');

EXEC DBMS_FGA.add_policy (object_schema     => user, object_name => 'MATT1', policy_name       => 'PROTECT_MATT1', audit_condition   => null, audit_column      => NULL, handler_schema    => user, handler_module    => 'MATT_TABLE_PROTECTOR_PKG.TABLE_PROTECTOR', enable            => TRUE, statement_types => 'UPDATE, DELETE');
```

That's it.  You're mostly protected now.

```
select * from matt1;
```

> ```
> 100 rows selected
> ```

```
delete from matt1 where a = 7;
```

> ```
> 1 row deleted
> ```

```
delete from matt1;
```

> ```
> ORA-28144: Failed to execute fine-grained audit handler
> ORA-20001: Unrestricted DML is not allowed on this table.
> ORA-06512: at "APPS.MATT_TABLE_PROTECTOR_PKG", line 15
> ORA-06512: at line 1
> ```

Because Oracle is smart enough to optimize out a lot of tautologies, you will also be protected against statements like:

```
delete from matt1 where 1=1;
```

or

```
delete from matt1 where 1<2;
```

But it is still easy to fool.  For example, this statement will work.

```
delete from matt1 where sysdate is not null
```

Comment: Hi Mathew. Thanks for giving details. If any possible to create Trigger for avoid the situation.

Comment: @KasiNathan The way you worded your question, a trigger would be a problem.  But you could do something similar with a trigger: you could have a compound trigger.  `BEFORE STATEMENT` -- set a PL/SQL package variable to zero.  `FOR EACH ROW` -- increment PL/SQL package variable and throw and exception if that variable is more than some threshold.  But the threshold would need to be an explicit number of rows, say 5000 rows.